# Android studio failed to complete Gradle execution

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have updated my android studio version to 2.2 and I was receiving error on project startup:

```
Gradle project refresh failed.
```

So I have searched about the problem and installed the Java SE Development Kit 8u101 and set JDK location to it.
After doing this error appeared :

```
    Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution. Cause: unknown.
```

I am stuck with this gradle execution error. I have uninstalled the android studio which I have updated and installed the new one.
I am also facing the above issues in newly installed version of android studio 2.2.
For now JDK location

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
```

And inside gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx256m
```

My system configurations are :

Processor -> intel core i3, RAM -> 4 gb, OS Type -> 32 bit Windows 7 Ultimate OS

Gradle console with --stacktrace --debug:

```
Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3813)
at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3800)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.doCreateTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:399)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:361)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:341)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:334)
at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.createTempFile(FileUtil.java:1479)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1064)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addLocalMavenRepoInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1057)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addLocalMavenRepoInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1023)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getExtraCommandLineArgs(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:345)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:175)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:768)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:752)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please help.

Comment: I am not sure if this will solve your problem. But you are supposed to have only one java version in your system. Hence if you have installed jdk1.8 then remove the other older versions.

Comment: Only one version is installed and that is Java SE Development Kit 8u101. There is no previous version.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is you're using 64-bit JDK on 32-bit system.

Comment: No I have checked it and its 32 bit.

Comment: Did you upgrade  android studio ?  if yes  . try install a clean version after uninstalling previous  android studio version with user data

Comment: I have done clean installation but no success

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And I could solve the following:

1. Uninstall Android Studio
2. Delete Android SDK
3. Uninstall all versions of JDK
4. Delete the folders .android, .AndroidStudio2.2 and .gradle of your user folder
5. Restart your computer
6. Download e reinstall Android Studio

Comment: Today when I turned on the computer and open Android Studio error returned

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't know what the problem really was but now I have moved to 64 bit Windows and solved the problem.