# Gradle 'MyApplicationProject' project refresh failed

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-gradle-plugin

My projects simply don't compile anymore. I can not sync my gradle file. The following error occurs when I try to compile:

```
Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed
Error:Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3813)
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3800)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.doCreateTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:399)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:361)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:341)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtilRt.createTempFile(FileUtilRt.java:334)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.createTempFile(FileUtil.java:1479)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1064)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addLocalMavenRepoInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1057)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleUtil.addLocalMavenRepoInitScriptCommandLineOption(GradleUtil.java:1023)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getExtraCommandLineArgs(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:345)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:175)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:768)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:752)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:238)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:73)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I do not know what caused this. But I would love to appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Looks like a null Pointer exception .. Can't be certain unless you include the code that caused this error and maybe some background like what you were doing when it first stopped working

Comment: What happened to me was exactly what is in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654466/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution) question. @mike510a

Comment: Thanks for the help. I solved the error and I posted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654466/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution/40565404#40565404) response.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19906308/6950238) answer:

1. Close Android Studio
2. Go to android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib
3. Delete (or better move them somewhere to have a backup) all gradle-*-1.8 files
4. Start Android Studio again and rebuild/refresh.

Comment: In my _C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\gradle\lib_ folder has no gradle-*-1.8 files

Comment: " gradle-*-1.8 " - is for Gradle  1.8 now it may be 2.14.1 or something like that

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it did not work. By removing the following error appear: NoClassDefFoundError: Worker exited due to exception: org/gradle/tooling/model/UnsupportedMethodException

Comment: I solved the error and I posted [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654466/android-studio-failed-to-complete-gradle-execution/40565404#40565404) response.

Answer (score 0):

Goto File=>invalidate caches/restart and select "invalidate and restart" clean and rebuild it will work.